# Calculate the volume of the solid generated by two regions

Tags: integration, area, solid-of-revolution

How can I calculate the volume of the solid generated by the S1 and S2 regions by rotating around the Ox axis and around the axis Oy?

S1 :
$0 ≤ x ≤ 2$

$0 ≤ y ≤ 2x − x^2$

---

S2:
$0 ≤ x ≤ π$

$0 ≤ y ≤ \sin^2(x)$

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***$S_1$***

[image]

$$\int\limits_{x=0}^2 \pi (2 x - x^2)^2\ dx = \frac{16 \pi}{15}$$

Can you do ***$S_2$***?

Comment: yes right, thanks very much @davidgstork

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

For the  rotation of a curve $y=f(x)$ around the $x$-axis, if the whole curve is on the same side of the $x$-axis for $a\le x\le b$, you have the formula
$$V=\pi\int_a^b f^2(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
For the second curve, you'll have to linearise $\sin^4x$.